# Determine Intersection and difference of infinitely countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been confused about how exactly write the answer to this question if you could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Let $A = \{3^k$| $k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ ; $B = \{l^3$| $l\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

a) Determine $A\cap B$.

b) Determine $A-B$.

Comment: Let's work at a). Pick a power of $3$, say $3^{258}$: how would you show that it is / isn't a cube?

Answer (score 1):

One way,$$A\cap B = \{3^k |k = 3p, p \in \mathbb{N}\} $$
$$A - B = \{3^k| k = 3p+1 \text{ or } k = 3p+2, p \in \mathbb{N}\}$$